# How can I rotate an object with random speed with some delays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Turn_Move : MonoBehaviour {
    public int TurnX;
    public int TurnY;
    public int TurnZ;

    public int MoveX;
    public int MoveY;
    public int MoveZ;

    public bool World;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (World == true) {
            transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime,TurnY * Time.deltaTime,TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }else{
            transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime,Random.Range(3,300) * Time.deltaTime,TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the random part :

```
Random.Range(3,300)
```

but sine it's changing the random numbers too quick the changes are almost not visible.
I want somehow to make that if for example the next random will stay for example 5 seconds at this speed number then move to the next random number and again stay at this number 5 seconds and so on.

Tried this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Turn_Move : MonoBehaviour {
    public int TurnX;
    public int TurnY;
    public int TurnZ;

    public int MoveX;
    public int MoveY;
    public int MoveZ;

    public bool World;

    private bool IsGameRunning = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        IsGameRunning = true;
        StartCoroutine(SpeedWaitForSeconds());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator SpeedWaitForSeconds()
    {
        var delay = new WaitForSeconds(3);//define ONCE to avoid memory leak
        while (IsGameRunning)
        {
            if (World == true)
            {
                transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime, TurnY * Time.deltaTime, TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
                transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.Rotate(TurnX * Time.deltaTime, Random.Range(3, 300) * Time.deltaTime, TurnZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
                transform.Translate(MoveX * Time.deltaTime, MoveY * Time.deltaTime, MoveZ * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            }

            yield return delay;//wait
        }
    }
}
```

but that just rotate the object once each 3 seconds. and not rotating it all the time with speed changing every 3 seconds.

Comment: i am usually a desktop or web developer, but when i need to delay any process in my applications using c#,  i use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Do not use threads like that in Unity. Use coroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways of delaying your randomisation. You can either add up Time.deltaTime until you reach a specific amout of time passed or you can use InvokeRepeating and call your if-case.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

If you need more help or code just say so.

EDIT: 
If the gameobject needs to rotate at a constant speed try using Rigidbody.addtorque
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html
but because it's a force remember to reset it before you set the new value.